# Click event fire when some element added to my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i click on my page link that time some element is added dynamically to page.
I want to fire click event on this new added element.But this element each time not added I want to fire click event when this element is added.Using javascript or jquery.
When new element is added page is load so I try to set timeout function and fire click event its work but some time it not work.

Comment: define click event after this element is added not put into the document.ready event

Comment: Please provide some code, that we can see what you did

Comment: where are code ??

Comment: Use dynamic binding on click `$(staticAncestors).on(eventName, dynamicChild, function() {});`

Comment: when new element is added  page is load so I try to set timeout function   and fire click event its work but some time it not work.

Comment: Do you mean you want to *raise*/*fire* the click event?  Or add a new click handler?

Comment: Yes i want fire click event not handler

Comment: How do you add the new element to the page?

Comment: $("MyId").click() This MyId is id of that element i want to fire this click event. its same Id for each time i try this using timeout function but some time it not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

        document.querySelector('#myId').addEventListener('click', function() {
          alert('Showing more details');
        });

        // ensure that event listner is added before triggering click event
        document.querySelector('#myId').click();
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <a id ="myId" >Show details </a>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want to fire click event when new element added to my page not handler.When new element is added page is load so I try to set timeout function and fire click event its work but some time it not work

Comment: how is this element added? which element do you want to trigger `click` on?

Comment: $("MyId").click() This MyId is id of that element i want to fire this click event. its same Id for each time i try this using timeout function but some time it not work.

Comment: is $("MyId") available when you trigger `click()` on it?

Comment: Yes. I set timeout 1500 but some time it take time to add this element.When it take time that time it not work. I want to fire this when this element added

Comment: I think it's better if we talk in chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126797/discussion-between-maximus-and-admin).

Comment: @Admin, so did you try the solution?